# Do static_assert on every other type in a template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

How can I do `static_assert`s (or other checks) on every other type in a template?

```
template<typename... Ts> //T1,T2,T3,...
struct foo {
  //How can I
  //for T1,T3,T5,T7,...
  //do some checks, for example:
  //static_assert(std::is_default_constructible<Tn>::value,"invalid type");
  //static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<Tn>::value,"invalid type");
};
```

Comment: Just pass a flag with the template every time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try this:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename... Ts>
struct default_constructible;

template <typename T>
struct default_constructible<T>
{
    static constexpr bool value = std::is_default_constructible<T>::value;
};

template <>
struct default_constructible<>
{
    static constexpr bool value = true;
};

template <typename T, typename U, typename... Ts>
struct default_constructible<T, U, Ts...>
{
    static constexpr bool value = std::is_default_constructible<T>::value && default_constructible<Ts...>::value;
};

template <typename... Ts>
struct foo
{
    static_assert(default_constructible<Ts...>::value, "");
};

class A { A() = delete; };

template class foo<int, bool>;      // Compiles
template class foo<int, bool, A>; // Does not compile
```

***[Demo](http://ideone.com/aKJxRz#view_edit_box)***

Comment: Didn't know you can plonk a `static_assert` in the middle of a class definition.

Comment: just so people don't get confused about @LightnessRacesinOrbit's comment; it's perfectly legal to "*plonk a `static_assert` in the middle of a class definition*".

Comment: Turns out `static_assert`s are declarations. Amazing!

Comment: Is there a need for the second template (with the 1 parameter)? Can't this be put right into the third?

Comment: In any case I can't compile your code (even after fixing typos). I think this is because there is no "end condition" to end the recursion.

Comment: The code still does not compile. I get this error in your third template (at the second `static constexpr bool value = ...`): `Implicit instantiation of undefined template 'default_constructible<>'`

Comment: @roger.james Hmmm, but my code works perfectly in the demo -- http://ideone.com/aKJxRz#view_edit_box Try to copy and paste my code again.

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
template <template <typename...> class Pred, typename ...Args> struct check_odd;

template <template <typename...> class Pred>
struct check_odd<Pred> : std::true_type { };

template <template <typename...> class Pred, typename T>
struct check_odd<Pred, T> : Pred<T> { };

template <template <typename...> class Pred, typename T1, typename T2, typename ...Args>
struct check_odd<Pred, T1, T2, Args...>
{
    static constexpr bool value = Pred<T1>::value && check_odd<Pred, Args...>::value;
};
```

Usage:

```
static_assert(check_odds<std::is_arithmetic, T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>::value,
              "Not all odd types are arithmetic.");
```

Obvious routes of generalization are parametrizing the combiner (currently hardcoded as "AND", or `&&`), and giving the predicate additional parameters.