# Avoiding creating a variable in this template code

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I have a template:

```
template<typename... Ts> //T1,T2,T3,...
struct foo {
  //my struct
};
```

I want to do `static_assert` checks on T1,T3,T5,... (the "odd types") and on T2,T4,T6,... (the "even types") separately.

I have found this simple solution:

```
template<size_t N, typename... Ts>
struct perform_checks {};

template<size_t N, typename T, typename U, typename... Ts>
struct perform_checks<N, T, U, Ts...> : perform_checks<N, Ts...>
{
  //check for odd types
  static_assert(std::is_default_constructible<T>::value,"failure");

  //check for even types
  static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<U>::value,"failure");
};
```

The `N` parameter allows it to end. I use it like this:

```
template<typename... Ts>
struct foo {
  perform_checks<0,Ts...> hello;
};
```

This seems to be working fine. But is it possible to avoid the `hello` variable? I never use it for any other purpose.

Comment: `static_assert(AllOf<perform_check<Ts>...>{}, "type check failed");`, `AllOf` left as an exercise for the reader. ;)

Comment: @Xeo: And `OddTypes` and `EvenTypes` that is what is being asked for also left to the reader :)

Comment: Didn't you just [ask this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17350329/596781)?!

Comment: @KerrekSB In a way yes, but I ended up finding my own solution that has this drawback of an extra `hello` variable. This question is about my particular solution only.

Comment: You assume that `Ts` always has an even number of types. Is that a problem?

Comment: @Casey I assume it's always an even number of parameters. I guess I should also static_assert that somehow.

Comment: @roger.james I'll edit my answer then.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas I'm a complete beginner in this. Can you please put your OddTypes in an answer?

Comment: @roger.james: You can look at the answer by Cassio. I would have done it differently but not better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Derive `foo` from `perform_checks<>` privately:

```
template <typename... Ts> struct foo : private perform_checks<Ts...> {
 // stuff
};
```

Oh, and get rid of the `N` parameter that you don't need:

```
template <typename... Ts> struct perform_checks {};
template <typename T> struct perform_checks<T> {
  template <typename U> struct dependent_name_hack : std::false_type {};
  static_assert(dependent_name_hack<T>::value,
                "Odd number of parameters not acceptable.");
};
template <typename T, typename U, typename... Ts>
struct perform_checks<T, U, Ts...> : perform_checks<Ts...> {
  //check for odd types
  static_assert(std::is_default_constructible<T>::value,"failure");

  //check for even types
  static_assert(std::is_copy_constructible<U>::value,"failure");
};
```

Comment: Bah, `static_assert(false,...)` is not dependent on a template parameter, and triggers at template definition time instead of instantiation time as intended. Insert hack to make it depend on a parameter.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `enable_if`[1](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/enable_if/) (and boost::mpl) in more-or-less the following way:

```
#include <boost/mpl/and.hpp>
template<size_t N, typename... Ts>
struct perform_checks {};

template<size_t N, typename T, typename U, typename... Ts>
struct perform_checks<N, T, U, Ts...> : perform_checks<N, Ts...>
{
    typedef boost::mpl::and_<std::is_default_constructible<T>::type, 
        std::is_copy_constructible<U>::type> type;
};

template < class... Ts,
       class = typename std::enable_if<perform_checks<0, Ts...>::type>
struct foo {
  //my struct
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The only purpose of `foo` in the OP is triggering the check when it's instantiated. That's why you need the variable `hello`: it's an instantiation of `foo`.

I would rather follow the approach of traits in `<type_traits>`. More precisely, I would turn `perform_checks` into `class` (or `struct`) that has public `static constexpt bool` member called `value` which is `true` or `false` depending on whether the given types pass the test or not. Then I would use a single `static_assert` to stop compilation if `value` is false.

My solution, which assumes that the number of template type arguments is even, follows:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename First, typename Second, typename... Others>
struct perform_checks :
    std::integral_constant<bool,
        perform_checks<First, Second>::value && // Checks First and Second
        perform_checks<Others...>::value        // Recursively "calls" itself on Others
    > {
};

// This specialization finishes the recursion and effectively performs the test
template<typename First, typename Second>
struct perform_checks<First, Second> :
    std::integral_constant<bool,
        std::is_default_constructible<First>::value && // Checks First
        std::is_copy_constructible<Second>::value      // Checks Second
    > {
};
```

Here is a simple test:

```
struct NonDefaultConstructible {
    NonDefaultConstructible() = delete;
};

struct NonCopyConstructible {
    NonCopyConstructible(const NonCopyConstructible&) = delete;
};

int main() {
    static_assert(perform_checks<int, double>::value, "Failure");
    static_assert(perform_checks<int, int, double, double>::value, "Failure");
    static_assert(!perform_checks<NonDefaultConstructible, int>::value, "Failure");
    static_assert(!perform_checks<int, NonCopyConstructible>::value, "Failure");
    static_assert(!perform_checks<int, int, double, NonCopyConstructible>::value, "Failure");
}
```

Notice that no variable was created.